# How is this thing unbreakable, yet seems broken?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power

This hilt appears throughout *The Rings of Power*:

> [image: Hilt]

If you look at it, it looks broken.  At least, a large part of the sword is missing.  However, in Episode 6, we found [Arondir](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Arondir) was not able to destroy the hilt:

> [image: Arondir attempting (and failing) to destroy the hilt]

This seems inconsistent.

**Question**: How is the hilt unbreakable, yet seems broken?

Comment: Unbreakable by man or elf does not mean its not breakable by other means.

Answer (score 3):

### Because magic

It is a common trope in Fantasy: you magical item (or magical creature) with comparable power to destroy other magical items. For example, Sauron was able to break Narsil - an extremely powerful sword - like a twig, barely by stomping on it (at the same time, the sword was still powerful enough to hurt its destroyer):

In similar fashion, the sword Anduril (which was made from reforged Narsil) was tarnished when Aragorn beheaded The Mouth of Sauron

[image]